# Input does not take in variable

Tags: python, input

I'm a beginner in Python, and I'm trying to make a code that asks you your name and remembers it for the rest of the program.

```
print("What will you name yourself?")
name_input = input("> ")
name = name_input
print("Your name is: ") + name
```

The error traceback message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\#######\My Stuff\Deskemon.py", line 16, in <module>
print("Your name is: ") + name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Please help!

Comment: I see no reason to downvote, nor close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to add `name` (a `'str'`) to the return value of `print(...)` (which has`'NoneType'`), resulting in the message that the '+ operator' does not support this combination of operand types.

Hey... look !  that's what the error message *does* say! :)

Probably you need:

```
print("Your name is: " + name)
```

Note: the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method is also very useful for these kinds of things:

```
print("Your name is: {}".format(name))
```

Comment: Also, `name = name_input` is absolutely useless. Just replace the next use of `name` by `name_input`

Comment: @plg: although this is correct, I believe this comment would be better placed underneath the question itself, since it has no relation whatsoever with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("What will you name yourself?\n> ")
print("Your name is: {}".format(name))
```